# .net GridView Control for online catalogue, will it work?

Tags: .net, gridview

Trying to build an online catalog for a web shop. Is the GridView control configurable enough for this, i.e. each item, for example product picture, title, price, qty field, 'add' button, and then move right to the next one, basically a typical online shop layout, or is another control better suited to this layout type?

I have previously always worked in classic asp and pretty much coded everything manually.

Thanks, R.

Comment: Thanks guys, i did a little research (huh) and think the listview is probably the way to go.  I am having a little experiment with myself to see how little code I can get away with not writing!

Its all fun and games... too much starbucks, i'm feelin a little dizzy!

Answer (score 0):

The GridView will work but I would strongly suggest the use of a Repeater control as it is considerably more efficient!

If you are used to doing everything manually you will love the Repeater!  Also...is there a chance for you to move to ASP.NET MVC in this application?  You will love this framework over webforms if you are coming from asp classic.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, after some research I almost decided to go with the repeater but have since opted for the listview...  I really want to see what .net can do for me...

Thanks.

Comment: Just know that most of these "repeating" type of controls are based off of the repeater.  So if performance is what you are looking for rather than ease of use by way of templating...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET 3.5, check out the new [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx). This will give you more advanced templates than a simple Repeater but you still retain precise control over the rendered HTML.